# placement new in a (virtual) parent class

Tags: c++, crtp

I have this CRTP:

```
template <class T>
struct S {
  void clear() { new (this) T; }
};

class SS : public S<SS> {
  int i = 5;
};

int main() {
  SS s;
  s.clear();
}
```

Is `clear()` guaranteed to work as expected? Does it even matter if `S` is virtual or not?

For the matter we can assume all the classes inheriting `S` won't have anything but primitive or POD types, so no fancy constructors and destructors.

I compiled with gcc and valgrind didn't seem to complain but it feels weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recreate the child type at the right place in memory you'll have to cast the `this` pointer.

Also, if you do not call the destructor, you have to assert that the type is trivially destructible:

```
template <class T>
struct S {
    void clear() {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<S, T>);
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>);
        new (static_cast<T*>(this)) T;
    }
};
```

Valgrind did not warn about anything since the `this` from the base was the same as the derived class, you did not overwrite any memory past what was allocated.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Whats the point of the static_cast? Can it change the actual value of this?

Comment: @user2717954 yes. The this pointer could either point to the base or the derived, since they may have different offset in memory, depending on their content or if multiple inheritance is used

Comment: follow up question. std::is_trivially_destructible<T> requires the destructor of T is not virtual. is there some work around if S is virtual?

Comment: or even if SS (the class inheriting S) is virtual while S itself isn't

Comment: @user2717954 yes it must not be virtual. If you want a non-trivial or a virtual destructor, you must call it using `static_cast<T*>(this)->~T()` before creating the new object

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the `static_cast<T*>(this)`, I also suggest to call dtor on the object first.

```
template <class T>
struct S {
    void clear() {
        auto this_ptr = static_cast<T*>(this)
        this_ptr->~T();
        new (this_ptr) T();
    }
};
```